# Question Bans on Meta Sites besides MSE

Tags: support, post-ban, per-site-meta

This question is more for curiosity than knowledge, but it might still be useful to know.

Is it possible to obtain automatic question bans on meta sites besides Meta Stack Exchange? If so, how much lower is the threshold? I ask because downvotes on Meta have little effect overall and can indicate disagreement, so I would imagine that implementing a question ban system on a meta site would be hard to implement.